Gambler's Ruin Problem with infinite bank's fortune
As one can guess for the title, I'm dealing with the Gambler's Ruin Problem in the infinite bank's fortune case.
Usually we start with the Standard Gambler's Ruin Problem, which is:
We've got a gambler betting on a sequence of games. She (why not a female) bets \$1 per game with probability $p$ of winning and probability $q=1-p$ of losing. The game ends when the gambler, beggining with $\$x$, gets ruined (fortune 0) or she  gets an objective fortune $a$  (we start by supposing $a\in\mathbb{N}$ a finite quantity).
It is well known that if we call $f(x,a)$ the probability of reaching fortune $a$ beggining with fortune $x$, then
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
f(x,a)=&\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\frac{1-(q/p)^x}{1-(q/p)^a},&\hbox{ if }p\neq q\\
x/a,&\hbox{ if } p=q=1/2,
\end{array}\right.
\end{array}
$$
Now, we can make $a\rightarrow\infty$ to pass to the bank's infinite fortune case (in the beggining case we can understand the bank's got initial fortune $a-x$ so the bank's role would be that where it is also a  player but with the probabilities $p$ and $q$ reversed, i.e., winning with probability $q$ and losing with probability $p$).
So we let $a\rightarrow\infty$ just to find that, in this new case, the probability $f(x)$ of "reaching infinite fortune" starting from fortune $x$ is:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
f(x)=&\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
1-(q/p)^x,&\hbox{ if }p>q\\
0,&\hbox{ if }p\leq q\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{array}
$$
My problem is in the "reaching infinite fortune" sentence. To be more precise, let me get down to what I expect can be a more formal setting:
Fixing an initial fortune $x$, I present a random variable $X$ which can take three values: 0, infinity and -1:
$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
X:&\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^\infty\{-1,1\}&\rightarrow&\{-1,0,\infty\}
\end{array}
$$
where we understand $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^\infty\{-1,1\}$ as the product probability space, where the $\sigma$-algebra over each $\{-1,1\}$ is that of every subset, with $P(-1)=q$ and $P(1)=p$.
The random variable $X$ takes values in the following way: if $\{s_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^\infty\{-1,1\}$ is a sequence of 1's and -1's, then $X((s_i))=0$ if there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x+\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n s_i=0$, $X((s_i))=\infty$ if there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x+\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n s_i=0$ and  $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty s_i=\infty$. And finally, $X((s_i))=-1$ if neither of the other two cases is fulfilled.
So, the question is: how to prove that (when $p>q$) $P(X=\infty)=1-(q/p)^x$ and that, when $p\leq q$, $P(X=\infty)=0$ (avoiding the limit way, I mean) and that $P(X=-1)=0$ in any case (at least, that is what I expect is true).
I'm sorry for lack of brevity. Thanks for reading and I hope to have been clear enough for you to help me.

One resource that covers this is Markov Chains by Norris, Section 1.3 (particularly Example 1.3.3)

For the p>q case I interprete your question as "how justified are we in disregarding the possibility of sn staying in moderate amount (nor infinite nor zero)?", but for p=<q, I'm struggling to understand what do you mean. BTW isn't the fact that the probability of ruin tends to one sufficient for the probability of its compliment (X being infinite or -1) to get zero?

@Ziv, even when Norris' book don't use the formal setting I wrote about, it is true that we can use it (plus the limit way up there) to prove that $P(X=0)=1-P(X=\infty)$ in every case, which is enough for me to relax for the moment. Thank you very much indeed!

Let $X_n=x+\sum_{k\leq n}\xi_k,x \in \mathbb{N}$ be a random walk where the increments $(\xi_n)_n$ are IID, $P(\xi_1=1)=p,P(\xi_1=-1)=q=1-p$. If $p>q$ then the law of large numbers allows us to state that $X_n/n \to p-q>0$ a.s., so $X_n=n(X_n/n)\to \infty$ a.s. Let $\tau_0:=\inf\{n:X_n=0\}$. In this particular case, we are then interested in computing $P(\tau_0=\infty)$, that is the probability of never reaching ruin, and thus reaching infinite fortune without ever reaching zero. We have $P(\tau_0=\infty)=1-(q/p)^x$.

Indeed, let $p>q$. If we choose $a=q/p<1$ then $(a^{X_n})_n$ is a martingale. Optional stopping allows us to state that $a^x=E[a^{X_{n\wedge \tau_0}}]$ where $n\wedge \tau_0:=\min(n,\tau_0)$ is a bounded stopping time. We can then decompose $E[a^{X_{n\wedge \tau_0}}]$ in the following way:
$$E[a^{X_{n\wedge \tau_0}}]=P(\tau_0<n)+E[a^{X_n}\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_0\geq n\}}]$$
Now note $a^{X_n}\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_0\geq n\}}\leq 1$. We can then use the fact that $a^{X_n}\to 0$ a.s. (because $X_n\to \infty$ a.s.) to justify dominated convergence and claim $E[a^{X_n}\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_0\geq n\}}] \to 0$. By sending $n\to \infty$ we get
$$a^x=\lim_nE[a^{X_{n\wedge \tau_0}}]=P(\tau_0<\infty)$$
and so $P(\tau_0=\infty)=1-a^x$.
